# how com(ocx) using c# runtime loading

Tags: c#, com

please help me.
using C#, using ocx object
i don't know how to use.

1. load dll
2. get types
3. create instance
4. fail to create instance have params
5. public _DMulticidEvents_displayDbgMessageEvent(string strMessage)

-- C# source --

```
public void load(){
var DLL = Assembly.LoadFrom(p_filePath);

Type type1 = DLL.GetType("AxMULTICIDLib.AxMulticid");
Type type2 = DLL.GetType("AxMULTICIDLib._DMulticidEvents_displayDbgMessageEventHandler");
Type type3 = DLL.GetType("AxMULTICIDLib._DMulticidEvents_displayDbgMessageEvent");

var cid1 = Activator.CreateInstance(type1);  -> is ok
var cid2 = Activator.CreateInstance(type2); -> params error not create!!

}

private void axMulticid1_displayDbgMessage(object sender, AxMULTICIDLib._DMulticidEvents_displayDbgMessageEvent e)
{
            displayMsg(e.strMessage);
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're problem is. Can you elaborate?

Comment: It looks like the event may not be registered.  Did you register event?

Comment: `AxMULTICIDLib._DMulticidEvents_displayDbgMessageEventHandler` and `AxMULTICIDLib._DMulticidEvents_displayDbgMessageEvent` are interfaces, not classes. You cannot create an instance of an interface.

Comment: Not interfaces, this is an AxHost wrapper.  var evt = type1.GetEvent("_DMulticidEvents_displayDbgMessageEvent");  var dlg = Delegate.CreateDelegate(type2, this, "axMulticid1_displayDbgMessage");  evt.AddEventHandler(cid1, dlg);